# how to show response data on list dynamically data in android?

Tags: android

can you please tell me how to show  response data on list dynamically data in android ?.I am able to get data from server , and I make a array from response .Now I want to
show on list view .I make a xml in which i write text view .And then After what I have to do ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!--  Single List Item Design -->
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:textSize="16dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>
```

package com.example.twat;

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ProgressDialog progress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                showProgressDialog("Please Wait...");
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                WebServiceRequestManager manager = new WebServiceRequestManager();
                return manager.getMethod("httpa/destinationdashboard?crsCode=add");
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                System.out.println("Respose : " + result);
                hideProgressDialog();
                try {
                    JSONObject js =new JSONObject(result);
                    String stationName[] = null;
                    JSONArray arr=js.getJSONArray("data");
                    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                        stationName[i] = arr.getJSONObject(0).get("tocName").toString();

                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.execute();
    }

    public void showProgressDialog(final String msg) {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (progress == null || !progress.isShowing()) {
                    progress = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", msg);
                   progress.setCancelable(false);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void hideProgressDialog() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    if (progress.isShowing())
                        progress.dismiss();
                } catch (Throwable e) {

                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: You should use listviw to show data in list

Comment: You can use android listview with some adapter(BaseAdapter)

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference from a "static" array. Just use a ListView and pass to it the String[] of items.

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-listview-with-adapter-example.html) and also [this](http://androidexample.com/Create_A_Simple_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=65&aaid=90) in order to know more about listviews and how to use and inflate them.

Hoping the clue will suffice.